# google reCAPTCHA V2 "Use of undefined constant .."

Tags: captcha

I'm implementing google's reCAPTCHA V2. It works almost perfectly except for the following error located in the recaptchalib.php:

Notice: Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success' in (script location)

https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA/blob/master/php/recaptchalib.php

Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is a code review question and not an Info Sec question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
if (trim($answers [success]) == true)
should be:
if (trim($answers ['success']) == true)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was due to me refreshing the captcha validating PHP page after already submitting the captcha - Some sort of time out.